# Can I save object prototype in local storage?

Tags: javascript, prototype

I have JS object with custom methods as prototype (e. g. `Foo.prototype.myAwesomeMethod`). If I load my object in a `localStorage` and get it later I'll loose these methods.

```
var foo = new Foo()
console.log(foo.myAwesomeMethod()) // WIN

localStorage.setItem('foo', foo)

foo = localStorage.getItem('foo')
console.log(foo.myAwesomeMethod()) // FAIL...
```

Is it possible to save the prototype of the object in the `localStorage` ? If not, how to properly re-instantiate the class?

Comment: Most browsers these days will store simple objects in local storage, but you should still consider it a storage for strings, a substitute for cookies if you will, and storing prototypes probably isn't the best idea.

Comment: Why do you even need this? Local storage is for data, not logic.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```
function Foo() {
  this.bar = 1;
}
Foo.prototype.myAwesomeMethod = function () {
  return "And the winner is " + this.bar;
}
var foo;

window.onload = function () {
  foo = new Foo();
  foo.bar = 3;
  console.log(foo.myAwesomeMethod()); // "And the winner is 3"
  var test = JSON.stringify(foo); //localStorage.setItem('foo', foo);
  foo = JSON.parse(test); // = localStorage.getItem('foo');
  foo.__proto__ = new Foo(); // <--------------
  console.log(foo.myAwesomeMethod()); // "And the winner is 3"
});
```

EDIT:
my previous code was untested and didn't work, this is the working code

Comment: I agree, but if it did `foo.bar = 1` my new Foo() will erase it.

Comment: nope, you replace the prototype, not the object properties

Comment: You should have ```oo.__proto__ = Foo;``` not with new Foo()